# Laplace transform involving the gamma function.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform

Does anyone know how to evaluate the following integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-qs}\alpha^{s}}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s)}\text{d}s  $$ where $q,\,\alpha > 0$? I've done some digging in usual resources on tables of integrals, but nothing has jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does anyone know how to evaluate the following integral ?*

No. No one knows how to evaluate that integral. The **proof** is by **reduction to the absurd:** If anyone would have known how to express that integral in closed form, then the much simpler case with $q=0,~\alpha=1,$ and only one $\Gamma(s)$ in the denominator would also have been known to possess a closed form. Unfortunately, no such form is known for the famous [Fransen-Robinson constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fransen-Robinson_constant). *QED*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about a representation in terms of other special functions, a series, or an infinite product?

Comment: @BillyPilgrim: As far as special functions are concerned, the same observation holds. As for the latter two, I have no idea. I'd start by google-ing *series representation Fransen-Robinson* or *product representation Fransen-Robinson*, to see if by chance any might exist, though I wouldn't hold my breath. Then, if I'd find any, I'd try and draw some inspiration from them, and adapt them to the current problem.