# How I can show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(n^5\right)}}=1$ ? Any closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, irrational-numbers

This question is related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3297280/156150) which it were related to irrationality inverse square root of Gamma function , I  plug the following  sum : $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(n^5\right)}}$$in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SetPrecision%5BSum%5B1%2F%28Sqrt%5BGamma%5Bn%5E5%5D%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1+%2CInfinity%7D%5D%2C30%5D) with  precision $30$ ,it returned the sum  to exactly $1$, I have used The standard definition of $\Gamma(n) =(n-1)!$ trying to get its partial sum but it were complicated to me for evaluation, Now ,Is that sum interpreted any standard result ? and how I can evaluate it since it is rational ?

Comment: The first term is 1, and the other terms are absolutely miniscule and don't show up with 30 decimal places, but they are non-zero.

Comment: PARI/GP computes $1.0000000000000000110278059538310609033$ for the sum of the first 10 terms.

Comment: bc -l gets .0000000000000000110278059538310609032942060847778971258447535062193870006468053968418970017788817337 as the 2nd term.

Comment: Asking many times the same question doesn't change the answer

Comment: @kimchilover. I agree with you. Suming the first, second and third terms gives $1000$ exact decimal figures.

Comment: @kimchilover Nice to see someone using bc:)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment section,

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(n^5\right)}} \neq 1.$$

Adding the first $10$ terms together, we get

$$1.0000000000000000110278059538310609032942060847778971258447535062193870006468053968418970017788817337127$$

---

You can use [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2F%28Sqrt%5BGamma%5Bn%5E5%5D%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%20%2C10%7D%5D) to convince yourself.